# Table notes of sidewaystable mess up after using threeparttable

Tags: tables, tabularx, threeparttable, sidewaystable

After making a table with the threeparttable package, the tablenotes that I have for tables made with the sidewaystable package completely mess up. See for instance the picture below

[image]

Does anyone know how to make it such that the table notes for the sidewaystable span the whole table?
Some working example code is given below:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[font=small,labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{hanging}
\usepackage[a4paper,top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm,left=2.5cm,right=2.5cm,marginparwidth=1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{newfloat}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{float}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[H]

\centering
\caption{This is the caption of table 1}
\begin{tablenotes}[flushleft] 
\small\setlength{\extrarowheight}{1.5pt}
\item Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla  
\end{tablenotes}
%\ra{1}
\begin{adjustbox}{max width=\textwidth}
\begin{threeparttable}
\centering
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{\begin{tabular}{l c c c}
\toprule
Panel A \\
\midrule
& Entire Sample & Advisory  & Execution Only  \\
\midrule
Row 1 & 0   & 0& 0 \\
Row2 &  0   & 0& 0 \\
Row3 & 0    & 0& 0 \\ 
Row4 & 0    & 0& 0 \\ 
Row4 & 0    & 0& 0 \\ 
\end{tabular}}

\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{\begin{tabular}{l c c c c c c }

\toprule
Panel B \\
\midrule
  & S1 & S2 & S3 & S4 & S5 & H-L \\ 
\midrule
Row1 &0000  &0000 &0000 &   0000    &0000 & 0000\\
Row2&0000   &0000 &0000 &   0000    &0000 & 0000\\
Row3&0000   &0000 &0000 &   0000    &0000 & 0000\\
Row4 &0000  &0000 &0000 &   0000    &0000 & 0000\\
Row4 &0000  &0000 &0000 &   0000    &0000 & 0000\\
  \\
\hline
Panel C \\
\midrule
 & S1 & S2 & S3 & S4 & S5 & H-L \\
\midrule
Row1 &0000  &0000 &0000 &   0000    &0000 & 0000\\
Row2&0000   &0000 &0000 &   0000    &0000 & 0000\\
Row3 &0000  &0000 &0000 &   0000    &0000 & 0000\\
Row4 &0000  &0000 &0000 &   0000    &0000 & 0000\\
Row4 &0000  &0000 &0000 &   0000    &0000 & 0000\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}}
\end{threeparttable}\label{tab:1}
\end{adjustbox}
\end{table}





\begin{sidewaystable}[ht]
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{3pt}
\centering
\caption{This is the caption of table 2}
\begin{tablenotes}[flushleft] 
\footnotesize\setlength{\extrarowheight}{1.5pt}\item Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla 
\end{tablenotes}
%\ra{1}


\setlength{\tabcolsep}{4.5pt}
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{\begin{tabular}{l c c c c c c c c c c c c  c  c  c c c c c c}
\toprule
 Event & \multicolumn{2}{c}{From 1 to 2} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{From 2 to 3} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{From 3 to 4} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{From 4 to 5} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{From 5 to 4} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{From 4 to 3} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{From 3 to 2} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{From 2 to 1} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{UP} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{DOWN} \\
 \cmidrule(lr){2-3} \cmidrule(lr){4-5} \cmidrule(lr){6-7} \cmidrule(lr){8-9} \cmidrule(lr){10-11}  \cmidrule(lr){12-13} \cmidrule(lr){14-15} \cmidrule(lr){16-17} \cmidrule(lr){18-19} \cmidrule(lr){20-21}  
month  & $\overline{\text{CSAF}}_t$  & $t$-value & $\overline{\text{CSAF}}_t$ & $t$-value &$\overline{\text{CSAF}}_t$ & $t$-value &$\overline{\text{CSAF}}_t$ &$t$-value &$\overline{\text{CSAF}}_t$ &$t$-value &$\overline{\text{CSAF}}_t$ &$t$-value &$\overline{\text{CSAF}}_t$ &$t$-value& $\overline{\text{CSAF}}_t$ &$t$-value & $\overline{\text{CSAF}}_t$ &$t$-value& $\overline{\text{CSAF}}_t$ &$t$-value \\ \midrule
  & &\multicolumn{3}{l}{Panel A}\\
 \addlinespace[1ex]
   \hline
  1 & 0 &   0 & 0 & 0 & 0&0 & 0 &   0 &0 &  0 & 0&  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &0 &  0 & 0 &0 \\
  2 & 0 &   0 & 0 & 0 & 0&0 & 0 &   0 &0 &  0 & 0&  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &0 &  0 & 0 &0 \\
   3 & 0 &  0 & 0 & 0 & 0&0 & 0 &   0 &0 &  0 & 0&  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &0 &  0 & 0 &0 \\
    4& 0 &  0 & 0 & 0 & 0&0 & 0 &   0 &0 &  0 & 0&  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &0 &  0 & 0 &0 \\
     5 & 0 &    0 & 0 & 0 & 0&0 & 0 &   0 &0 &  0 & 0&  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &0 &  0 & 0 &0 \\


      6 & 0 &   0 & 0 & 0 & 0&0 & 0 &   0 &0 &  0 & 0&  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &0 &  0 & 0 &0 \\

\\ 
 \hline
\addlinespace[1ex]
 & &\multicolumn{3}{l}{ Panel B}\\
 \addlinespace[1ex]
  \hline
 1 & 0 &    0 & 0 & 0 & 0&0 & 0 &   0 &0 &  0 & 0&  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &0 &  0 & 0 &0 \\
  2 &  0 &  0 & 0 & 0 & 0&0 & 0 &   0 &0 &  0 & 0&  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &0 &  0 & 0 &0 \\
   3 &  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0&0 & 0 &   0 &0 &  0 & 0&  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &0 &  0 & 0 &0 \\
    4 &  0 &    0 & 0 & 0 & 0&0 & 0 &   0 &0 &  0 & 0&  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &0 &  0 & 0 &0 \\
     5 & 0 &    0 & 0 & 0 & 0&0 & 0 &   0 &0 &  0 & 0&  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &0 &  0 & 0 &0 \\
      6 & 0 &   0 & 0 & 0 & 0&0 & 0 &   0 &0 &  0 & 0&  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &0 &  0 & 0 &0 \\
\\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
}
\label{tab:2}
\end{sidewaystable}



\end{document}
```

Comment: Do not use resizebox or adjustbox on a table as this will lead to inconsistent fo t sizes. Probably this is also the reason for the different widths of table notes and table.

Comment: Actually when I delete the threeparttable stuff, all sideways table notes work perfectly fine. I do realize that using resizebox or adjustbox messes with the font of the tables, and will ultimately have to change this.

Comment: What are the contents of the tablenotes environment in your real document? Do you use \tnote inside of your table? If you don't use that command, there is no need for the table notes environment.

Comment: Also make sure the exam ple actually compiles without error. There are `\item` missing in the `tablenotes` and `\text` is not defined as you don't load `amsmath`. Note that `\text` is the wrong command to use in that context use `\mathrm`.

Comment: I am not using \tnote in any of my tables. Should I get rid of the table notes environment?

Comment: @daleif Sorry about this. I am working in overleaf and it did compile, though I do see the errors now, thanks for pointing that out. I will try to get rid of the errors and update my working example.

Comment: So, the text inside of the tablenotes environment is just some descriptive text? If so, you should be able to just place that text inside if sidewaystable, right before the tabular. The tablenotes environment should be unnecessary here.

Comment: We have suggested to overleaf that when there are compilation errors it should be much clearer to the user that they need to stop and fix this error. That little red button is easily overlooked

Comment: @leandriis This almost works. The only thing that I do not like about it is that it doesn't give a 'block' of text (e.g. when a word is too large, it gets shifted to the next line which makes it such that the table notes do not look very elegant).

Comment: How will the contents of your actual table look like? Will all cells just contain numbers/contents that are shorter than the corresponding column headers? If so, you could consider transposing the entire table in order to avoid rotating the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the following gets closer to what you want to achieve:

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[font=small,labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{hanging}
\usepackage[a4paper,top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm,left=2.5cm,right=2.5cm,marginparwidth=1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{newfloat}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{float}

\begin{document}


\begin{sidewaystable}[ht]
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{3pt}
\caption{This is the caption of table 2}
 Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla 
\medskip

\centering
\scriptsize
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{3.75pt}
\begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}l *{20}{c}}
\toprule
 Event & \multicolumn{2}{c}{From 1 to 2} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{From 2 to 3} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{From 3 to 4} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{From 4 to 5} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{From 5 to 4} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{From 4 to 3} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{From 3 to 2} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{From 2 to 1} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{UP} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{DOWN} \\
 \cmidrule(lr){2-3} \cmidrule(lr){4-5} \cmidrule(lr){6-7} \cmidrule(lr){8-9} \cmidrule(lr){10-11}  \cmidrule(lr){12-13} \cmidrule(lr){14-15} \cmidrule(lr){16-17} \cmidrule(lr){18-19} \cmidrule(lr){20-21}  
month  & $\overline{\text{CSAF}}_t$  & $t$-value & $\overline{\text{CSAF}}_t$ & $t$-value &$\overline{\text{CSAF}}_t$ & $t$-value &$\overline{\text{CSAF}}_t$ &$t$-value &$\overline{\text{CSAF}}_t$ &$t$-value &$\overline{\text{CSAF}}_t$ &$t$-value &$\overline{\text{CSAF}}_t$ &$t$-value& $\overline{\text{CSAF}}_t$ &$t$-value & $\overline{\text{CSAF}}_t$ &$t$-value& $\overline{\text{CSAF}}_t$ &$t$-value \\ \midrule
  & &\multicolumn{3}{l}{Panel A}\\
 \addlinespace[1ex]
   \hline
  1 & 0 &   0 & 0 & 0 & 0&0 & 0 &   0 &0 &  0 & 0&  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &0 &  0 & 0 &0 \\
  2 & 0 &   0 & 0 & 0 & 0&0 & 0 &   0 &0 &  0 & 0&  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &0 &  0 & 0 &0 \\
   3 & 0 &  0 & 0 & 0 & 0&0 & 0 &   0 &0 &  0 & 0&  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &0 &  0 & 0 &0 \\
    4& 0 &  0 & 0 & 0 & 0&0 & 0 &   0 &0 &  0 & 0&  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &0 &  0 & 0 &0 \\
     5 & 0 &    0 & 0 & 0 & 0&0 & 0 &   0 &0 &  0 & 0&  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &0 &  0 & 0 &0 \\


      6 & 0 &   0 & 0 & 0 & 0&0 & 0 &   0 &0 &  0 & 0&  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &0 &  0 & 0 &0 \\

\\ 
 \hline
\addlinespace[1ex]
 & &\multicolumn{3}{l}{ Panel B}\\
 \addlinespace[1ex]
  \hline
 1 & 0 &    0 & 0 & 0 & 0&0 & 0 &   0 &0 &  0 & 0&  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &0 &  0 & 0 &0 \\
  2 &  0 &  0 & 0 & 0 & 0&0 & 0 &   0 &0 &  0 & 0&  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &0 &  0 & 0 &0 \\
   3 &  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0&0 & 0 &   0 &0 &  0 & 0&  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &0 &  0 & 0 &0 \\
    4 &  0 &    0 & 0 & 0 & 0&0 & 0 &   0 &0 &  0 & 0&  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &0 &  0 & 0 &0 \\
     5 & 0 &    0 & 0 & 0 & 0&0 & 0 &   0 &0 &  0 & 0&  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &0 &  0 & 0 &0 \\
      6 & 0 &   0 & 0 & 0 & 0&0 & 0 &   0 &0 &  0 & 0&  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &0 &  0 & 0 &0 \\
\\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
\label{tab:2}
\end{sidewaystable}



\end{document}
```